How to avoid uploading the full .jar file on every update
I am facing a little issue while deploying a new version of any of my Spring boot Apps.
A .jar file containing some basic Spring boot dependencies can easily reach 80Mo, which is not a big problem but still becomes annoying when deployment is frequent or when connection speed degrades for some reason.
No matter how minor the change is, the whole new .jar must be uploaded even if 99.999% of it is the same as the previous one.
Generating the .jar in the production doesn't seem to be ideal.
The goal is to be able to update the Apps with the minimum transferred data. How can this goal be achieved?
EDIT
a typical pom.xml would be:

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifact</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
    <name>app</name>
    <description>...</description>
    <url/>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2023.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents.client5</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient5</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents.core5</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore5</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc11</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.database.nls</groupId>
            <artifactId>orai18n</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>33.0.0-jre</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>



Sounds like you are using a "fat" jar where all the dependencies are rolled into one.  Please describe how you are building and assembling your code.

exacly, spring-boot-maven-plugin does the job, check the EDIT

To avoid uploading the full.jar file with every update, you can use the following strategies to minimize transferred data.

Use Jib for containerized deployments.

Use delts deployments (Resync or similar tools).
E.x: You can use re-sync like this
rsync -avz --progress /path/to/app.jar user@remote:/path/to/destination/


Use versioned dependency management.
For maven:


    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot.experimental</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-thin-launcher</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.28.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

